# Use of Guard.Against in a function that take a stream as input

Tags: c#, function, stream, arguments, illegalargumentexception

You write a method that takes a stream as input:

```
    public static class ClassA {
    public static void FunctionA(Stream stream) {
        Guard.Against(stream == null, "stream is null");
        1. Guard.Against(stream.position != 0, "stream position is not 0");
        2. stream.position = 0
        3. //nothing
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

Should you

1. Guard against the position not being 0
2. Set the stream position to 0 yourself
3. Don't do anything

What is considered as best practice? I'm leaning towards setting it yourself but I'd like to hear any problems that might arise from that decision.

Comment: Is this method exposed in a public API, or is it public only within the scope of the application? Will the method ever be called with a stream position that isn't zero, except in the case of a legitimate programming error?

Comment: Assume that its a public api. As far as the method being called with a stream position other than 0, I don't think so.

Comment: `I'd like to hear any problems that might arise from that decision` - Not all types of streams support `stream.position = 0`, so I would go with 1)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If and only if it's a *definite* programming error to call `FunctionA` with a stream that isn't at position 0, use option 1.

However, you should consider whether or not your method should care about the position of the stream that's passed, and the constraints that it places on the client if it does. The client owns that stream. They may read from or write to the stream before calling your method, and it restricts the client to enforce that the stream must be at position 0 before calling `FunctionA`. It's up to the client to ensure that the stream is passed to your method with the right position, and in light of that, I'd recommend option 3.

I would avoid option 2 entirely, unless it's very well-documented - silently resetting the position to 0 is likely to cause confusion for those using your method.